# Select with exceptions?

Tags: regex

I need to create a regular expression that finds anything after a string except for 2 words:
I have:

```
Transport input telnet
transport input ssh
transport input tftp
transport input lat
transport input pat
```

What i need is an expression that will find tftp, lat and pat or anything after transport input except for telnet and ssh:
Something like:

```
transport input (.*) except (telnet|ssh)
```

Thanks

Comment: Please specify what language / regex engine are you using, as each one has it's own quirks and limitations.

Comment: Which language are you using ?

Answer (score 4):

Use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
transport input (?!(?:telnet|ssh)$)(.*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bO8iZ0/8)

Comment: You don't need the back-reference, this is enough: `transport input (?!telnet|ssh)(.*)$`

Comment: @PedroLobito no, if we use your regex then it won't match `ssh-foo`. OP asks for not to match an exact word `telnet` or `ssh`

Comment: Nop, my regex  matches `transport input ssh-foo`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76215/discussion-between-pedro-lobito-and-avinash-raj).

Comment: I guess you're talking abut my first comment, I'm talking about my solution on this page. Miss-understood...

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
transport input (.*)(?<!telnet|ssh)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nS9iQ1/1)

---

## Regex Explanation:

```
transport input (.*)(?<!telnet|ssh)$


Match the character string “transport input ” literally (case insensitive) «transport input »
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*)»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below with the match ending at this position (negative lookbehind) «(?<!telnet|ssh)»
   Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «telnet»
      Match the character string “telnet” literally (case insensitive) «telnet»
   Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «ssh»
      Match the character string “ssh” literally (case insensitive) «ssh»
Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) (line feed) «$»
```

Comment: Reminder to the OP and viewers: Lookbehind isn't supported by Javascript's engine (nor by Tcl).

Comment: Yup, but the OP doesn't mention the language he's using, tks for pointing that.

Comment: True. I wasn't trying to attack your answer.  I just figured many viewers would think your answer didn't work when they tried it with Javascript and would be upset at that point.